# How do I script ruby IRB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I start irb I would like to run a series of commands e.g..

```
require 'active_model'
require './app/models/amodel'
require './app/models/bmodel'
ActiveModel::Base.establish_connection (..)
```

How can I feed a series of commands into IRB ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to load a Rails app. These manual steps are all unnecessary if you run such in your Rais app root

```
$ rails console
```

See more: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console